# Indesign error accessing the correct page

Tags: adobe-indesign

I want to open the multi-page "AI document" or "AI PDF" document we imported into Indesign by centering only the relevant page of that document on the screen with the "Edit Original" menu.  But by default it only centers the 1st page on the screen.  Can we develop this menu as "Edit Original Page" instead of "Edit Original"? Or is there a script for this?

[image: Menu redirected to wrong workspace]

Comment: Hey Hakan, Welcome to GDSE. I feel its not quite clear what your question is. When you open pdf's though file/place you can enable 'show options'. This dialog allows you to choose which page(s). There are scripts to bring this menu back. There are also scripts to open pdf and place every page accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The "edit original" is operating as intended. It is meant to merely *open the linked file in the originating application*. It is doing exactly as it's intended to do.

Simply because a specific artboard is placed into an image frame in InDesign, that does *not* mean that "edit original" will open the Illustrator file, *then navigate* to that specific artboard *within* the Illustrator file.  It is assumed if you know enough to use "edit original" then you know enough to navigate to the area within the original file you wish to edit.

If you want "edit original" to open and focus on the specific artboard for the placed image that is being clicked, you need to use *separate files* for the images as opposed to a single file with multiple artboards.